# Create Multi-level Index from array for an existing pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I would like to create multi-level index of a pandas dataframe from a numpy matrix?

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1) # just to keep the randomisation constant
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4))
array = np.vstack(((np.hstack((np.repeat(0, 4), np.repeat(1, 4)))),
                   (np.hstack((np.arange(0, 4), np.arange(0, 4))))))
```

How may I set `array` as the `multi-level index` of the pandas dataframe `df`?

## Update:

Expected output:

```py
           0           1           2            3
0   1    1.969143   -0.508107   0.136571    -1.450820
    2     -0.608492 1.542338    0.773752    1.089296
    3   -0.242616   0.847223    0.769937    1.065387
    4   0.424999    0.347806    1.530573    0.894608
1   1   -0.516036   1.641090    1.389866    -1.042482
    2   -0.054886   -0.645097   0.769537    -0.840258
    3   1.751442    -1.056358   -0.242556    0.580978
    4   -0.213291   -0.730862   0.997675     1.040655
```

Thanks!

Comment: kindly share your expected output

Comment: how do you want your output to be?

Comment: @sammywemmy sure!

Comment: @mas @ sammywemmy I have update the question with the expected output!

Comment: [pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html)

Comment: @anky it does create the index but I do not know how to append it back to the dataframe

Comment: `df.index = pd.MultiIndex...` you can always assign the index seperately.